# Need a math interpreter to be used in C#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, math

I wanted to know if there is any API which I can use to interpret logical and mathematical expressions, like the following:

```
var a = 89;
var result = 0;
if(a > 32)
result = IntegralOf(x^2 + e^(1-x),0,100)
else
.......
```

where the `IntegralOf` function will integrate the 1st argument expression, the second argument is the start value, and the 3rd argument is the end value.

For calculating integration and derivation etc, I have found some good libraries like **math.net**, but how should I interpret? Are there any APIs which do both interpreting and calculating? I had found some simple interpreters like **mathoparser** and **muparser** which just interpret simple mathematical expressions and not integrals or derivatives or conditional statements like MATLAB does.

I hope writing a custom interpreter is not what I have to do at last.

Comment: Your previous question was closed. Re-posting will only get you question-banned. You might have better luck on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, but I doubt they'll like the question too much either. In general 'which library should I use' questions are off topic on SO.

Comment: Just read the content first . This is not the same .

Comment: MATLAB and Mathematica do this; why do they not meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as far as I know you *will* have to write a custom interpreter. However, there are some tools that make this fairly straightforward. Take a look at the [Irony library](http://irony.codeplex.com/) which should be of great help. With it, you can define a grammar entirely in C# and parse it easily.

Comment: Thank you Manu . Will try it . I would have been able to get more responses if these research oriented questions were not been closed.

Comment: This seems to be same as MathOParser and muparser. Does Irony library have integration and derivation expression ?